# Sublime Text 3 wont show output (JAVA)

Tags: java, output, sublimetext3, println

I have a program in Java that takes the users input of a number, converts it to a string and then reverses the number and prints it out (e.g: INPUT: 789 OUTPUT: 987).

This program runs in every other IDE except Sublime Text 3. I'm assuming this is a problem with my copy of Sublime Text but I don't have the slightest clue whats causing it as all of the code is correct. Anyone have any ideas?

Code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reverse {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = reader.nextInt();
    String numbs = Integer.toString(number);

    String reverse = new StringBuffer(numbs).reverse().toString();

    System.out.println(reverse);

}
}
```

Comment: no need for stringBuffer.... you are not in a Multithreading app

Comment: I believe it's because of `reverse()` method. String class does not have it.

Comment: Is this homework? Cos I think you're missing the point if it is.

Comment: @DarshanMehta Thats is `StringBuffer reverse()` method.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse--

Comment: Sublime is a text editor, not an IDE. Your code as written clearly works fine except in Sublime. That is because Sublime doesn't let you interact with a running program by giving it input via stdin. You need to run it from a terminal to get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt rely too much on Sublime3 ... it is still a beta version

[image]

Keep using another IDE and try instead with a `StringBuilder`..

```
String reverse = new StringBuilder(numbs).reverse().toString();
System.out.println(reverse);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried few online documents to configure java on subl 3, beta relase from subl3 had only **Javac**, installed javatar plugin to run **java**.

1. javatar is a Java plugin available for subl, you can install it from **install packages** menu
2. create build javatar, it will create a file javatar.sublime-build
3. edit the javatar.sublime-settings

javatar.sublime-build

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac \"$file_name\" && java \"$file_base_name\""],
    "shell": true,
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

javatar.sublime-settings

```
{
    "java_executables":
    {
        "build": "javac",
        "lint": "javac",
        "run": "java",
        "script": "jrunscript",
        "version": "java"
    },
    "java_runtime_files":
    {
        "runtime":
        [
            "rt.jar"
        ]
    },
    "jdk_installation":
    {
        "linux":
        [
            "/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/"
        ]
    },
    "project_data":
    {
        "2": null
    }
}
```

Please note: it works for **static code**, not suitable for interactive where we need to get some input from user using Scanner.